# how to clear an NSMutableArray of custom objects without creating memory leaks?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

If I have an NSMutableArray of custom objects, how can I must easily clear the array without causing any memory issues?   Assume that the custom object class has a dealloc method in it which correctly released an instance variables etc.

For example is it ok to use the NSArray "removeAllObjects" method?

- If yes - how does this work - does "removeAllObjects" call the "dealloc" method on each object as it removes them
- If no - what would be the easiest approach to use?

**EDIT (after 4 replies)** - One last question of clarification after the great replies - I'm still not quite sure about the instance variables/properties in my custom object that I have set to retain?  These seem to be only released via the the "dealloc" method in my custom object class, where we do this manually along with [super release].

So if, re clearing an array, if I do a removeAllObjects, and then NSArray issues a "release" to my custom objects, but doesn't call "dealloc", then how do my instance variables get released?

Comment: No one should call `dealloc` other than the memory manager (or a subclass's `dealloc`).  `removeAllObjects` calls `release` on each object as it clears it from the array.

Comment: yep, if you see a `dealloc` in your code that is not part of `[super dealloc];` you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`removeAllObjects` will remove the object from the array. This process will send a release message to the object and this will decrease its reference count. When the reference count reaches zero the object will be deallocated.

don't do it like this, because it will leak.

```
NSObject *object = [[NSObject alloc] init];       + 1
[array addObject:object];                         + 1
[array removeAllObjects];                         - 1
                                                =======
                                                = + 1 -> Leak
```

this is the correct way:

```
NSObject *object = [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease]; + 1 (from alloc) - 1 (from autorelease)
[array addObject:object];                         + 1
[array removeAllObjects];                         - 1
                                                =======
                                                =   0 -> Object will be deallocated
```

Instead of calling removeAllObjects you could just release the array. If an array is deallocated everything that's inside of it gets released and if there is no other reference to the object it will be deallocated.

Comment: thanks - just added one question of clarification as an EDIT in my question if that's ok...

Comment: sorry for my late answer, but once the reference count reaches zero the system will call dealloc on the object. You don't have to do this.

Comment: With using ARC this situation is handled correctly by the system in first way, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Yep, just call `removeAllObjects`. Just to be sure, you don't call `retain` when you add an object to an array or when you create an array with objects. That's done for you automatically.

Regarding `dealloc`, again that will be done automatically, and you can't predict when.

The only thing you need to have in the dealloc is the array object itself. That is, assuming it's an instance variable or ivar?

To check everything is good, run the Analyzer using Product -> Analyze. And then give the app a profile in Instruments using the Leaks instrument to check that none of your code is causing any memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

The `dealloc` method is never called directly. Everything is done thru the `retain`/`release` mechanism (and the reference counting principle). So this is the `release` method that gets called, not the `dealloc` directly. The `dealloc` method is only called by the runtime if the last `release` call causes the reference counting (retainCount) of the object reaches zero, meaning that the object really is deallocated from memory as noone uses it anymore.

`NSArray` and all container classes in Cocoa (`NSDictionary`, `NSSet`, ...) do retain their values. So when you add an objet to a container like `NSArray`, it will `retain` that value. And when you remove that value (including when you call removeAllObjects") it will `release` it.

Memory Mgmt rules are easy to follow: but the only rule that matters it that you only have to call `release` or `autorelease` if you called `alloc`, `retain` or `copy` methods. That's always the responsability of the objet which did the `alloc`/`retain`/`copy` to call the `release`/`autorelease`. Never leave a `alloc`/`retain`/`copy` without a pending `release`/`autorelease` call to balance it (or you will have leaks), but on the other hand never call `release`/`autorelease` if you didn't do the `alloc`/`retain`/`copy` call yourself.

Good example 1:

```
MyClass* obj = [[MyClass alloc] init]; // here you do an alloc
[myArray addObject:obj]; // the NSArray "myArray" retains the object obj
// so now you can release it, the array has the responsability of the object while it is held in the array
[obj release]; // this release balance the "alloc" on the first line, so that's good

[myArray removeAllObjects]; // there the object held by the array receive a release while being removed from the array. As nobody retains it anymore, its dealloc method will be called automatically.
```

Good example 2:

```
MyClass* obj = [[MyClass alloc] init]; // here you do an alloc
[myArray addObject:obj]; // the NSArray "myArray" retains the object obj
// so now you can release it, the array has the responsability of the object while it is held in the array
[myArray removeAllObjects]; // there the object held by the array receive a release while being removed from the array. But your own code still retains a reference to it (because of the "alloc" on first line) so it won't be removed from memory right now
[obj release]; // this release balance the "alloc" on the first line, and as nobody retains the object anymore, its dealloc method will be called and it will be deallocated from memory
```

Good example 3:

```
MyClass* obj = [self getSomeObjectFromAnotherMethod]; // here you don't have an "alloc" on this line
[myArray addObject:obj]; // the array retains the object
[myArray removeAllObjects]; // the array release the object while it removes it from the array
// no need to call "release" here as there is no "alloc" done in the scope of this code
```

Bad example:

```
MyClass* obj = [self getSomeObjectFromAnotherMethod]; // here you don't have an "alloc" on this line
[myArray addObject:obj]; // the array retains the object
[myArray removeAllObjects]; // the array release the object while it removes it from the array
[obj release]; // Crash here! obj does not exists anymore and has been deallocated from memory before this line!
```

Comment: thanks - just added one question of clarification as an EDIT in my question if that's ok...

Answer (score 1):

Basically `removeAllObjects` method sends `release` message to all the objects. The *release* method ***decrements the objects reference count***. And if the reference count of an object reaches `0` then the `dealloc` message will be sent to the object.

The answer to your question is calling `[array removeAllObjects]` is completely safe. By the way if you don't want the array anymore you can directly call `[array release]` which releases all its objects as well as the array.

Comment: You say it sends a release method ipso facto.  Is that because of ARC?